# Explode Array-Nested Array Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON structure with multiple nested arrays, like this:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "packages": [
        {
            "packageId": 1010,
            "clusters": [
                {
                    "fieldClusterId": 101010,
                    "fieldDefinitions": [
                        {
                            "fieldId": 101011112999,
                            "fieldName": "EntityId"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using spark sql to flatten the array to something like this:

| id | packageId | fieldClusterId | fieldId | fieldName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1010 | 101010 | 101011112999 | EntityId |

The query ends up being a fairly ugly spark-sql cte with multiple steps:

```
%sql
with cte as(
  select 
    id
    explode(packages) as packages_exploded
  from temp),
cte2 as (
  select
    id,
    packages_exploded.packageId,
    explode(packages_exploded.clusters) as col
  from cte),
cte3 as (
  select 
    id,
    packageId,
    col.fieldClusterId
    explode(col.fieldDefinitions) as col
  from cte2)
select 
    productId,
    productName,
    fieldClusterId,
    fieldClusterName,
    col.*
from cte3
```

Is there a nicer syntax to accomplish this multiple level explosion?

Comment: Is it required to solve it only using SQL?

Comment: yes the process is metadata driven and requires a spark-sql query

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would implement:

```sql
SELECT id,
       packageId,
       fieldClusterId,
       inline(fieldDefinitions)
FROM
  (SELECT id,
          packageId,
          inline(clusters)
   FROM
     (SELECT id,
             inline(packages)
      FROM TABLE_NAME))
```

Comment: i'm hoping for a cleaner syntax than a multi-stage cte or succession of subqueries.  do you think it's possible to do without either of these complexities?

Comment: It is not possible because you're exploding arrays from a nested object. If `packages`, `clusters` and `fieldDefinitions` were array columns in a flatten structure you could use `inline(arrays_zip(packages, clusters, fieldDefinitions))` but that's not the case.